# How to create one only decimal number in C?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, double

I've a problem: I would need to concatenate 3 double numbers into one only double number. For example, I've:

```
a = 40.000000;
b = 56.000000;
c = 10.236330;
```

I need the following number: `40.5610236330`. The integer part is defined by the first two cyphers of `a`, the first two decimal cyphers are the integer part of `b` and the other decimal cyphers are all the cyphers of `c`. I've tried with:

```
k = a+(b/100)+(c/1000);
```

But due to approximation error, the result is `40.570236`. Could you help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: The "approximation error" will always happen when working with floating point types. If you want to avoid it, think of how to do the same with integers (we could help you with that if you described the *actual* problem you are trying to solve).

Comment: If you need exact values, you need to use chars or ints.  Using floats will always give you approximate results.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: At least you could try `...+ c/10000`.

Comment: Typo: divide `c` by `10000`, not `1000`.

Comment: With a `float` on an x86/x86-64, you expect the error to be around the 7th digit of precision. On a `double`, the 16th. After the operations in question, there's no way it gets promoted to the third. This is NOT floating-point error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point calculation always loose some precision.

But `40.570236` instead of `40.5610236330` is too much off.

The big error you see is because of a simple bug in your code.

You need `k = a+(b/100)+(c/10000);` (i.e. `c` is to be divided by 10000)

Maybe it would be more clear if you did `k = a+(b/100)+(c/100/100);`

But never expect floating point calculation to 100% precise. It's not even certain that the number `40.5610236330` can be represented in `float/double`

And further, the input values them self may be imprecise:

```
double c = 10.236330;
printf("%.20f\n", c);
```

Output:

```
10.23633000000000059515
```

Comment: is there any type of data wich allows me to represent 40.5610236330?

Comment: @domandestack *Is there any type of data which allows me to represent 40.5610236330?* Not a common type, no.  Most data types are designed to solve scientific or engineering problems, or occasionally math problems, but definitely not number theory problems — that is, not where every single decimal digit actually matters.  Type `double` can represent that number 40.5610236330 to within 0.000000000000005%, but not exactly.  To represent that many digits exactly, you need either a string type, or a *decimal* [multiprecision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) type.

Comment: The IEEE-754 [decimal64 floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) could represent that number exactly, and some versions of gcc do support this format natively (as `_Decimal64`), but I haven't been able to test it due to lack of library support, and I don't believe its use is at all widespread.

Comment: And, seriously, regular old `double` can represent that number adequately well.  If you printf it using `%.10f`, `%.11f`, `%.12f`, `%.13f`, or `%.14f`, you get the right answer.  It's not until `%.15f` that you start seeing anomalies (at least, with a well-written implementation of `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

There is enough precision in a double variable to store a number of 12 significant digits (though your question does not really state how many digits `c` has).

```
double k= a + b * 0.01 + c * 0.0001;
```

will work. But when you display it, be sure to use a format with 10 digits after the decimal point (`%.10f`) so that rounding restores the correct decimals.